# Showing all layers except the active one as backdrop during liquify

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In liquify tool, if I choose "All Layers" as the backdrop, both the original version and the distorted version of the active layer will be visible:

[image]

I found it causing unnecessary visual confusion. I'd prefer something like this:

[image]

In other words, All the other layers are rendered as the backdrop, except the active one (the one that is being liquifying). Is that possible?

Comment: ermm... the `Show Backdrop` options....

Comment: @Scott yeah I'm asking how to make this exact option show all layers except current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the soontobeliquified layer with a layer mask. Create mask and fill it with black:

[image]

Liquify it as you like. Be sure the layer (not the mask) is selected in the layers panel when you start Liquify. Have all layers as your Backdrop. The mask hides the original Layer A in the work window, but the version under work is well visible:

[image]

Delete the layer mask when you are ready:

[image]

Comment: It's a bit tedious but it does what I want. Thank you!